# Is it possible to populate a hash using a `for` loop?

Tags: ruby, hash

I want a hash that holds ints from 1 to 18 as the keys. I want the hash to look like this:

```
myHash = Hash.new
myHash[1] = "free"
myHash[2] = "free"
...
myHash[18] = "free"
```

I want to know if there's a nicer way to do this, such as using a `for` loop. Will something like:

```
myHash = Hash.new
for i in 1..18
myHash[i] = "free"
```

work, or will it just create 18 keys called `i`?

Comment: What happened when you tried running the above code?

Comment: Also keep in mind that in Ruby you can set default values for a hash using `myHash = Hash.new('free')'`. It might not be what you need in this case, but it is good to know.

Comment: @SCraig If your keys are integers, why would you like to use a Hash in the first place instead of an Array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`for` loops](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop) are rarely used. I would suggest [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html#method-i-each):

```
hash = {}
(1..18).each { |i| hash[i] = 'free' }
hash
#=> { 1=>"free",  2=>"free",  3=>"free",  4=>"free",  5=>"free",  6=>"free",
#     7=>"free",  8=>"free",  9=>"free", 10=>"free", 11=>"free", 12=>"free",
#    13=>"free", 14=>"free", 15=>"free", 16=>"free", 17=>"free", 18=>"free"}
```

You can also pass the initial object - i.e. the empty hash - into the loop using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
hash = (1..18).each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = 'free' }
```

Within the block, the second argument `h` refers to the passed-in hash, so it can be modified. At the end, `each_with_object` returns the filled hash.

Another option is to use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
hash = (1..18).map { |i| [i, 'free'] }.to_h
```

This builds an intermediate array `[[1, 'free'], [2, 'free'], ...]` and converts it to a hash afterwards using [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

Answer (score 3):

Your hash is called myHash, not hash. Then, in Ruby we use each, not for. And your variable should be my_hash, not myHash. Also, you missed the end keyword for your for. So:

```
my_hash = Hash.new
(1..18).each { |index| my_hash[index] = "free" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a super quick one liner that doesn't require you manually loop, initialising an array with a count will set the size of the array to this, and apply the block to each index. `Hash[]` will then take the array (of arrays) and convert it to a hash. `i` will be zero based, so you need to use `i+1`

```rb
my_hash = Hash[Array.new(18) { |i| [i+1, "free"] }] # Pure Ruby
my_hash = Array.new(18) { |i| [i+1, "free"] }.to_hash # Only works in Rails
my_hash = Array.new(18) { |i| [i+1, "free"] }.to_h # Only works in Ruby 2.3
```

Comment: I've updated the code example to assign the hash, as well as added a few variations on the method

Answer (score 1):

```
myHash = Hash.new
for i in 1..18
myhash[i] = "free"
```

Well, just run it. It results in an error: `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`. Ah yes, a missing `end`. Let's add indentation, so we can see what's inside the loop and what is not.

```
myHash = Hash.new
for i in 1..18
  myhash[i] = "free"
end
```

Another error: `in 'block in <main>': undefined local variable or method 'myhash' for main:Object (NameError)`. Ruby says it doesn't know `myhash`. Stupid Ruby. `myhash` is a Hash, we said so on the first line. Oh wait... we named it `myHash`, not `myhash`.

```
myHash = Hash.new
for i in 1..18
  myHash[i] = "free"
end
```

Run it: no errors, no output at all. Add one line to inspect `myHash`:

```
myHash = Hash.new
for i in 1..18
  myHash[i] = "free"
end
p myHash
```

And there it is, myHash: `{1=>"free", 2=>"free", 3=>"free", 4=>"free", 5=>"free", 6=>"free", 7=>"free", 8=>"free", 9=>"free", 10=>"free", 11=>"free", 12=>"free", 13=>"free", 14=>"free", 15=>"free", 16=>"free", 17=>"free", 18=>"free"}`.

Comment: A smarter Ruby would add ``did you mean: `myHash'?`` to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but I've found a method in the Hash documentation (ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) which might be helpful here.

It looks like you're trying to make a hash return the string 'free' when you haven't defined a value.

As you know, when you recall a key in a hash which has not been defined, it returns nil:

```
h = {:foo => bar}
h[:baz]
# nil
```

You can change the default result of an unknown key using #default

```
h = {1 => 'Cat', 2 => 'Dog'}
h.default = 'Free'
h[1]
# 'Cat'
h[4]
# 'Free'
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
([*1..18].product ["free"]).to_h
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes. This is possible, but your question doesn't make sense. You must have some array as below. There are a number of advanced solutions for this. But for beginner, I would give you this solution.

```
a =["first","second","third",......]
h = Hash.new
a.each_with_index do |value,index|
  h.merge{index => value}
end
```

This would create a complete hash for you.

Comment: Well, a `SyntaxError` is preventing your code from running.